# Receiving Unhealthy Internet Connection To Firebase Firestore Despite Very High Internet Speed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am running an ionic angular app. When I get this error:

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.14.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
>   This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

Firebase does not return my data or accept my changes. This is despite my internet speed being very high. The average download speed is 5-15 mbps but I have 10x that at 151 mbps. Not sure what to do. Anyone else having this issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although bad internet connection is the most common cause of this error, its not the only one. There are a number of thing that can be occurring, assuming you are running this is a local environment these could be some of the causes:

- Antivirus or Firewalls are blocking your connection;
- AdBlockers are blocking the connection;

Also, it is possible that some Firebase Rules are not being met while accessing the Firestore, so it might be a good idea to check them.

Finally, as you can see on this [GitHub Report for Firebase Javascript SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2923), it's possible that there is a bug causing this on some versions of Firebase (7.14.6 and below), you can find some workarounds for the issue in there that could work for your case or you could upgrade to the most recent version, which is 7.15.0 according to the [Firebase SDK Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#latest_sdk_versions).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks, but unfortunately getting a new browser didn't work. I think this is an error from firebase. I will be contacting them.